# What dependency should be used to get row id from resources without using R class?

Tags: android, android-studio

Like this:

```
val myString = getString(string.hello_from_vb_activity)
```

Not like this:

```
val myString = getString(R.string.hello_from_vb_activity)
```

[An example from Google](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/0905d0e307ef457a4c37511a542edfe3bdb4d2a3/ViewBindingSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/viewbindingsample/MainActivity.kt#L36)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import com.android.example.viewbindingsample.R.string
//import yourPackageName.R.string
```

you can import string like this then it will look as you expect

By the way this does same job.

R.string.any_string

string.any_string

in both case you are using R class